# Must all env variables be prefixed with REACT_APP for use with yarn?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, yarnpkg

Using `create-react-app`, my environment variables are loaded from `.env` as long as they're prefixed with `REACT_APP_`, but not otherwise:

```
// .env
REACT_APP_API_KEY=1234
MY_FUNNY_API_KEY=5678

// index.js
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY) // 1234
console.log(process.env.MY_FUNNY_API_KEY)  // undefined
```

Running `yarn run env` (from `create-react-app`) shows`MY_FUNNY_API_KEY`, but it doesn't seem to be available from the app. Is there some way to access general environment variables without the `REACT_APP_` prefix?

Comment: did you read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ ?

Comment: @azium I guess that covers it. Frustrating that I can't remove those training wheels. I'm still interested in a custom solution that allows this -- I tried using `dotenv` in my `index.js` but was not able to make that work.

Comment: You need a prefix to stop *all* your environment variables being baked into your client build. CRA does this with dotenv and webpack's define plugin, as I show [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Client-environment-variables).

Comment: why dotenv didnt work? have you called its config function in your index.js? 
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()

Comment: what do you mean by training wheels? you can write a script that prefixes all your envs with REACT_APP at build time, and you can write a mdule that strips it at runtime if you want

Comment: Why you pretty certainly **do not** want to do that: https://wale.id.au/posts/iviewed-your-api-keys/

Comment: @Greg I'm not sure what you mean by a solution - I don't think there's a problem to solve. CRA (and others, e.g. Next) require a prefix to avoid leaking secrets. You can do whatever you like via the DefinePlugin (updated link from my comment above: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Dotenv#client-environment-variables), though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe was interested in being able to drop the REACT_APP_ prefix.  From what I'm seeing the "rewired" module seems to be a way forward here...